# Cambiar colores del comando ls en Linux

Tags: linux

Quisiera cambiar los colores del comando **ls** en mi partición de datos, ya que los directorios son poco legibles desde la consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es una partición **NTFS** que comparto con Windows y mi archivo **/etc/fstab** contiene lo siguiente para la partición:

```
/dev/sda4 /media/datos ntfs-3g rw,defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para cambiar el color en la terminal, debes de modificar tu archivo .bashrc.

Entras a la terminal:

```
nano $HOME/.bashrc
```

Agregas al final del archivo:

```
export PS1="\[$(tput setaf 1)\]\u@\h:\w $ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

Guardas (control + o) y luego cerras (control + x). Ahora cargas tu archivo que recién cambiaste.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Listado de opciones:

- tput bold – negrita
- tput rev – colores invertidos
- tput sgr0 – Restablecer todo
- tput setaf {CODE}– Establecer foreground color, ver color {CODE}

CODE de colores:

```
Color {code}    Color
0   Black
1   Red
2   Green
3   Yellow
4   Blue
5   Magenta
6   Cyan
7   White
```

Otra forma de cambiar colores es usando LS_COLORS:

Entras a la terminal:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS/master/LS_COLORS -O $HOME/.dircolors
echo 'eval $(dircolors -b $HOME/.dircolors)' >> $HOME/.bashrc
. $HOME/.bashrc
```

[Link](https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS)

Comment: Muchas gracias, utilicé LS_COLORS y funciona muy bien.

Comment: @akko por nada. Para ayudarnos estamos.

Comment: josego: veo que eres de Paraguay.  No sé si conoces [spanish.se], otro sitio de esta comunidad. En [esta publicación de Meta](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2484/1674) detallamos respuestas que tienen versiones en distintos idiomas. ¿Te apetece echarle un vistazo para ver si puedes incorporar la versión propia de Paraguay? ¡Muchas gracias!